# UiButton don't size correctly with Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, panel

I have a problem when I try to change screens , from iPhone X pro to iPhone 8 ( landscape mode). The button don't resize correctly when I make the change.What should I add to the Canva or buttons to get a better size.(Same issue for the panels)
[CanvaInspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7K0x.png)
[ButtonInspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPHOt.png)

Comment: What settings do you have for the button in question? The settings your showing are for you whole canvas, on top of that UI elements can scale many way like having a set width and height which is unaffected by the canvas size.

Comment: Try changing `Screen Match Mode` to `Shrink`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want your application to just work in landscape mode, then you can set the **Reference Resolution** as *X:1080 Y:1920*, set the **Match** value as *1* (this is based on how you want your UI to react, so you may want to keep it as 0), set your preview screen size as *1920x1080 Landscape*, and try to build your application based on that reference, it will make most of the things easier. Furthermore, if you anchor your UI elements properly, it will react to different resolutions without any problem. For the anchors and pivots, you may want to take a look at the [unity documentation for basic layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html).

However, if you want your application to work in both portrait and landscape mode, then the general idea is more or less the same, you may want to play with your reference resolution and match value (for example, setting the match value as 0.5 will make the UI resize by considering both height and width equally). [This](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) documentation can help you to understand it better.

I also know that some developers design different UIs for landscape and portrait mode separately and then activate/deactivate them based on the orientation of the phone. This can also be an option.